# Unobtrusive validation for the whole viewmodel in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel, unobtrusive-validation

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application and I'd like to have unobtrusive validation for several properties of the view model. Here's a simplified version :

ViewModel :

```
[AtLeastOne(new[] {"FirstName", "LastName"})]
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Validation attribute :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AtLeastOneAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private readonly string[] _propertyNames;

    public AtLeastOneAttribute(string[] propertyNames)
    {
        if (propertyNames == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyNames");
        if (propertyNames.Length < 2) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("propertyNames");
        _propertyNames = propertyNames;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var modelClientValidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = "AAAAA!!!",
            ValidationType = "atleastone",
        };
        modelClientValidationRule.ValidationParameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("propertynames", _propertyNames));
        return new[]
        {
            modelClientValidationRule
        };
    }
}
```

Although I have :

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

in Web.config and

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("atleastone", ['FirstName', 'LastName'], function (options) {
            alert('options!');
        });
    </script>
```

set in my view nothing is rendered for this validation. If I, for example, add [Required] for FirstName or LastName, data-* validation attributes are added.

How can I achieve this multi-property custom client-side validation?

WANT TO SEE / [DOWNLOAD THE WHOLE SOLUTION](http://andrei.rinea.ro/mvc-whole-model-client-side-validation.zip)?

Comment: Does your `AtLeastOneAttribute` has the `[AttributeUsage]` attribute?

Comment: I don't think so. did you register your custom validation method on the client side? something like: `jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.add("atleastone")`?

Comment: I added [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)] but nothing is being emitted. I get the feeling that this scenario is not covered..

Comment: I also added javascript to add an adapter with a dummy function (see update above) and still I get nothing.

Comment: This guy is saying that this is not possible : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5803339/1796

Comment: By carefully studying the ASP.NET MVC 4 source files I observed there is no output for the form in the case of unobtrusive validation. Therefore this won't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding custom validator in the client-side is a 2 step process:

1. First you need to `register` your `validator` (letting the `unobtrusive` framework knows that such validation exists - **but not adding the validation function itself**), as you did in `jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add`. you have to remember the function (third parameter) is **not the validator**, it's only intended for rule configuration (and could be ommited in your case).
2. Adding the `validator` itself:

   `jQuery.validator.addMethod("atleastone", function (value, element, param)
       {
       alert("validating 'atleastone'");
       });`

Comment: Yes, that's true. I added this code too but I don't have data-* attributes emitted and upon submission no validation either (no alert is being hit)..

Comment: Seems like i missed the whole point, that the validation is being done on the `viewModel` as a whole. sorry.

Comment: No problem. So you're saying the scenario is not supported?

Comment: I don't know, but that guy in the other post you mentioned eventually claimed it worked for him using another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7122108/1625737

Comment: Yes but he worked it around by tying it to a property instead. It's a valid work-around that I was already considering but I was still hoping for something a bit more elegant. If not, that's that and I'll do it like that.